# require.js and refactoring for unit testing

Tags: javascript, refactoring, requirejs

### overview

guys, recently I want to refactor my simple project, and I read some article about how to write testable javascript.

The basic idea I got is: to make data abstraction using constructor and selector (principle in SICP), but now because of the single pattern of require.js, I don't know how to organize my project.

### detail about the project

Here is the details:

The project is Tic-Tac-Toe with unbeatable AI. I implement it and decompose it into several part using require.js

The github address is: [hit me](https://github.com/Daniel-Xu/Tic-Tac-Toe)

### new thought

And right now: I begin to rewrite it, here is my new thought:

I create a game.js file for the whole game object and code is:

This is game **constructor**

```
function Game(pureCells) {
    this.currentPlayer = turnEnum.secondPlayer;
    this.board = this._createBoard(pureCells)
}
```

and I have some action function on it's prototype, here just list two:

```
Game.prototype.changeTurn = function changeTurn(){
    this.currentPlayer = - this.currentPlayer;
    if(currentPlayer == turnEnum.firstPlayer){
        if(document.board.real[1].checked) perfectMove();
    }else {
        if(document.board.real[0].checked) perfectMove();
    }
}

Game.prototype._createBoard = function(pureCells) {
    var allCells = []
    _.each(pureCells, function(el, i){
        allCells.push(new CellConstructor(el))
    })

    var board = new BoardConstructor(allCells)
    return board
}
```

And the **board.js** file is the same structure:

```
function Board(el) {
    this.element = el
    this.state = this._getState()
    this.winner = this._detectWin()
}

Board.prototype._getState = function() {
    var state = [];
    _.each(this.element, function(cell, i){
        state.push(cell.element.value)
    })

    return state;
}

Board.prototype.isFull = function(){
    if(_.contains(this.state, ''))
        return false
    return true
}
```

And you can see that the board is one of the dependency of game.

### The problem

Here I want to describe my problem:

Actually I have another file cell.js is also the same structure.  it's one of the dependency of board.

So now I want to use some function in both game and board, for example, when I handle the click event of cell, I need to detect the state of the board, and this function is in board.

first, I don't want to make circle dependency,

second, even though I inject board and game into cell.js file, but the instance I create will not the same with the one I will create in the main.js( the main file of require.js)

### give a hint

So sorry for the long description, and thank your patience for reading it. Please give some hint or advice! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shared.js -- no dependencies:

```
var sharedObj = {};
var sharedFunc = function () {}

define ({
    sharedObj: sharedObj,
    sharedFunc: sharedFunc
});
```

shared.js -- dependencies:

```
define(["dep1", "dep2"], function(dep1, dep2) {
    var sharedObj = {};
    var sharedFunc = function () {}

    return {
        sharedObj: sharedObj,
        sharedFunc: sharedFunc
    };
});
```

main.js:

```
requirejs(["shared", "cell"], function(shared, cell) {
    shared.sharedFunc();
    shared.sharedObj.something = "whatever";
    cell.someFunc();
});
```

cell.js

```
define(["shared"], function(shared) {
    function someFunc() {
         // you can do something with shared.sharedObj.something here
         // or call shared.sharedFunc() here
    }

    return {
        someFunc: someFunc
    };
});
```

Comment: about the `share.js`, is it good for writing object and function outside of the define?

Comment: If `shared.js` has no dependencies itself, it's fine like that. If it does, it should look like `cell.js` and return that object with sharedObj and someFunc. I just updated the answer to show how each would look.

Comment: yes, I know but the principle of require.js is to avoid clotting the global namespace, I think a subtly different way, I create a `share.js` file, and create a `game` object and return that

Comment: I'm fairly sure the inside of `shared.js` won't make it to the 'global' namespace, and neither will the inside of `main.js`. At the very least I can promise you the inside of the function in main.js is its own namespace, and won't be affected by whatever's in shared.js.

Comment: Hi, I still didn't solve it. because I create a share object, the share object depends on cell.js, so in cell.js, it will cause error!

Comment: So don't make the shared object depend on cell... that's circular dependency. Move parameters around, send callback functions, etc. so that cell reads and writes to shared, not the other way around.

Comment: but I need to use the board object to detect the whole state, and use game object to decide who's turn, if I could not have these two, it will become so difficult to do that. Unfortunately, these two both rely on cell.js

Comment: So add them from inside cell. Call a function inside `cell.js` that adds those objects to the `shared.sharedObj` object. Or add them from main.js or wherever your functions work, and add them to the shared object from there.